# How to use built-in modules in a function of a string using exec()

Tags: python, websocket

I am running a websocket python file. In that,I created built-in modules in a function using imp module and I am executing a function of string using exec() in another function.
I use those built-in modules as globals parameter in exec().
But when I use those modules in the function of string, it throws following error

```
'module' object has no attribute 'pose'
```

However,using those modules outside the function of string works perfectly and returns expected values. **But how to use inside the function?**.

Here is the full code

```py
import imp
import sys
import time

def generate_modules():
    destination_module = imp.new_module("destination")
    destination_module.destination = imp.new_module("destination")
    destination_module.destination.pose = "Hello World"
    # Define GUI module
    gui_module = imp.new_module("GUI")
    gui_module.GUI = imp.new_module("GUI")
    gui_module.GUI.robotPose = lambda: "robotPose"
    sys.modules["destination"] = destination_module
    sys.modules["GUI"] = gui_module
    return gui_module,destination_module

#Main function
def process_code():
    gui_module,destination_module = generate_modules()
    builtin_modules = {"GUI": gui_module,"destination":destination_module,"time": time}
    globl = globals()
    global_functions = globl.copy()
    global_functions.update(builtin_modules)
    sequential_code = """from GUI import GUI
from destination import destination
def generatepath():
    data = destination.pose
    pose = GUI.robotPose()
    return data"""
    dic = {}
    exec(sequential_code,global_functions,dic)
    func = dic["generatepath"]
    value = func()
    return value

process_code()
```

Thank you, any help is appreciated

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't just define the function directly? You can simply nest the ``def generatepath(): ...`` as a regular definition inside ``def process_code(self): ...``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The original code works as a server for websocket connection. That string I pass in exec() will be used in a python editor in a webpage. This is not original code. This is the sample code for the title of this question in short form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [`exec` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

> If exec gets two separate objects as globals and locals, the code will be executed as if it were embedded in a class definition.

Notably, [members of a class scope are not visible inside any nested scope.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names) The alias resulting from `from destination import destination` is only visible in the top scope, not inside the function.

A simple solution is to omit the locals dictionary:

```py
            ...
            exec(sequential_code,global_functions)
            func = global_functions["generatepath"]
            ...
```